# Wait for data from one task in a second independently scheduled task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have two forms to be filled out in order.  The first is required, and the second is optional.  Both kick off Celery tasks to process the form data, but the second requires data that the first task will write to the database.

I found that if the first and second forms were submitted very quickly, the second task will fail because the first task will not have finished and saved the data yet.

How can I ensure that the data from the first task is available to the second task?  The second task needs to be scheduled by the form submission, since the second form is optional, so it can't be a callback of the first task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data isn't there yet, continually retry the second task after a delay.  Or schedule the second task after the first with a callback.  Either way, you'll have to check if the data you need is available: if you schedule the second independently, you need to wait to see if the first data is there, if you schedule the second after the first you need to wait to see if the second data is there.

The following counts up until a stop value, waiting five seconds between retries, then prints 'done'.  This simulates retrying a task until the data you want is available.  Setting `max_retries` would be safer, in case the first task fails and doesn't set the needed data.  `bind=True` passes the task object as the first argument to the function.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, max_retries=None)
def count_until(self, stop, current=0):
    print(current)

    if current < stop:
        raise self.retry(args=(stop, current + 1), countdown=5)

    print('done')
```

```
count_until.delay(5)
```

---

It would make more sense to schedule a single task after the entire form is filled out.  Then you only have to schedule one task once and can be sure that it will have the full data.  This will also prevent having some data in an intermediate state if the user doesn't complete both forms.